# Terraform resources creation for a comma seperated list

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have 4 different type of resources ["file", "blob", "queue", "table"]. These resources are user chosen resources so some times this resources list could be just one of resource too.

I need to create these three resources in terraform module

1. **azurerm_private_endpoint**

- with private_service_connection unique to specific to the resource
- with subresource_names specific to the resource

2. data variable with **azurerm_private_dns_zone** specific to a resource type
3. create **azurerm_private_dns_a_record** specific to the resource type.

instead of duplicating the block of code. can you please suggest an efficient way to handle this usecase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Terraform's meta-arguments and dynamic blocks

```
variable "resources" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["file", "blob", "queue", "table"]
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "common_dns_zone" {
  # common configuration for all resource types
  name                = "common-zone"
  resource_group_name = "common-rg"
}

module "resources" {
  source = "./path/to/your/module"

  # loop through each resource type
  for_each = { for idx, resource_type in var.resources : idx => resource_type }

  # pass necessary parameters based on resource type
  resources = {
    for idx, resource_type in var.resources : idx => {
      resource_type = resource_type
      # add other specific attributes for each resource type
    }
  }
}
```

you can use dynamic blocks to create resources based on the provided resource types:

```html
variable "resources" {
  type = map(object({
    resource_type = string
    # add other specific attributes for each resource type
  }))
}

locals {
  # map resource types to their specific configurations
  resource_configurations = {
    "file"  = { /* specific attributes for "file" */ }
    "blob"  = { /* specific attributes for "blob" */ }
    "queue" = { /* specific attributes for "queue" */ }
    "table" = { /* specific attributes for "table" */ }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "resources" {
  for_each = var.resources

  name                = "private-endpoint-${each.value.resource_type}"
  # other common attributes

  dynamic "private_service_connection" {
    for_each = [var.resources[each.key]]

    content {
      # specific attributes for private_service_connection
    }
  }

  dynamic "subresource_names" {
    for_each = [var.resources[each.key]]

    content {
      # specific attributes for subresource_names
    }
  }

  # other dynamic blocks for resource-specific configurations
  dynamic "resource_configuration" {
    for_each = [local.resource_configurations[each.value.resource_type]]

    content {
      # resource-specific attributes
    }
  }
}

# add similar dynamic blocks for other resources (e.g., azurerm_private_dns_a_record)
```